# Call on a cell in Excel up to the first semi-colon

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells

I am using the =CONCATENATE function, and one of the cells I'm calling on I only want to take the value in the cell up to the first semi-colon. Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `LEFT` and `SEARCH` to pull back everything up to the semicolon.

```
LEFT(A1,SEARCH(";",A1) -1)
```

This example assumes the cell you are trying to get the first block from is `A1`.  `LEFT` is used to get everything from the left-most character up to a certain point, and `SEARCH` will return the character position of the first occurrence of `;`.  The `-1` is so that the semicolon is not included in the resulting text.

Comment: I think this may solve my problem, but I am struggling to use that in my concatenation function as I get an error regarding ='s. This is what my function looks like: =CONCATENATE("<a href=""url/", J5, ".asp"">hyperlink text</a>", "</br></br>", B5)  I need to do the search to what is J5 in my function. Can you help?

Comment: Just replace the `J5` in your formula with `LEFT(J5,SEARCH(";",J5)-1)`

Comment: I thought it was working, i jsut get #VALUE! I did exactly as you put

Comment: Hm.  Works fine on mine when I paste your formula into a sheet and add in my formula as described.  Did you get the commas and parenthesis right?  When I first posted the comment, I left off a comma.  #VALUE! in this formula usually means the search term (`;`) is not found.